# GlueContext necessary for AWS Glue jobs?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I checked a few of the questions but none seem to be what I am wondering.

I've created several Glue Jobs using GlueContext's syntax but now that I've learned a bit more about PySpark I wanted to create and execute a Glue Job fully scripted by me with PySpark.

Everything seems to run smoothly but the following command is doing nothing.
Even though the DataFrame in question is not empty, and the path is correct.

```
df.write.format('csv').option('header','false').save('s3_path')
```

This takes me to my question:
Every question/answer I read here uses the following:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3_path"}, format = "csv/parquet")
```

Am I forced to use glueContext's syntax to read/write from/to S3?
Or maybe there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Can you confirm if your df has data by df.show() and df.printSchema(). Also make sure you have proper permissions defined for the role that you are using with AWS Glue

Comment: If the question points towards assuring my "df" is indeed a Spark DF, it is.
And the permissions seem to be OK as well, given that using the glueContext writer method works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using glue for quite a long time now and I always prefer using pyspark dataframe writer instead of gluecontext writer as it provides more control.

For your case, I would say have a look at your sparkUI or cloudwatch logs and see if the task is being triggered or not and post the logs here if there is some issue.

To enable cloudwatch just enable the continuous monitoring.

and if you want to setup the sparkUI I have written a blog on the same

https://towardsdatascience.com/glue-spark-ui-6dab088929d9

Comment: I've been following CloudWatch logs closely and everything seems to be executing correctly. In fact, if I left the whole Glue Job intact while only changing the "writing part" from Spark Syntax to Glue's Syntax it would write no problem...